# Facebook Open Graph Title custom font

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm from Myanmar and currently, there are two different font standard in Myanmar. One is Zawgyi and another one is unicode.

I'm using font-face to support Unicode on my website.

Now, I want to support Unicode in Facebook open graph title.

How can I do so? Is it possible to embedded font in there?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to change font

Comment: Did you find any way to do this or any info about it?

Comment: @Stone, unfortunately, there is no way to do that at the moment.